# Fast implementation of Rolling hash

Tags: c++, hash

I need a Rolling hash to search for patterns in a file. (I am trying to use the [Rabin-Karp string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).

I understand how a good **Hash** works and how a good **Rolling Hash** should work but I am unable to figure out how to efficiently implement the *divide* (or inverse multiplication) when rolling the hash. I also read rsync uses rolling version of *adler32* but that doesn't looks like a random enough hash.

Ideally it will be great if you can point me to an optimized C/C++ implementation, but any pointers in the right direction will help.

Comment: For anyone who got here by searching rolling hash and multiplication inverse. You only need to divide (or use the multiplicative inverse) if your rolling hash implementation need to support variable length and you probably don't need this if you want to do Rabin-Karp. Some pointers on how to use the inverse in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6nuXg0BISo) and my attempt implementation in [python](https://pastebin.com/BGuxv1cM).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cipher's "prime base" idea should work decently - though the solution he posted looks a bit sketchy.

I don't think there's any need for inverse multiplication in this method.
Here's my solution:

Say the string we currently have hashed is "abc", and we want to append "d" and remove "a".

Just like Cipher, my basic hash algorithm will be:

```
unsigned hash(const string& s)
{
    unsigned ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        ret *= PRIME_BASE; //shift over by one
        ret += s[i]; //add the current char
        ret %= PRIME_MOD; //don't overflow
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now, to implement sliding:

```
hash1 = [0]*base^(n-1) + [1]*base^(n-2) + ... + [n-1]
```

We'd like to add something at the end and remove the first value, so

```
hash2 = [1]*base^(n-1) + [2]*base^(n-2) + ... + [n]
```

First we can add the last letter:

```
hash2 = (hash1 * PRIME_BASE) + newchar;
=> [0]*base^n + [1]*base^(n-1) + ... + [n-1]*base + [n]
```

Then simply subtract the first character:

```
hash2 -= firstchar * pow(base, n);
=> [1]*base^(n-1) + ... + [n]
```

An important note: you have to be careful about overflow. You can choose to just let it overflow unsigned int, but I think it's much more prone to collision (but also faster!)

Here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const unsigned PRIME_BASE = 257;
const unsigned PRIME_MOD = 1000000007;

unsigned hash(const string& s)
{
    long long ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        ret = ret*PRIME_BASE + s[i];
        ret %= PRIME_MOD; //don't overflow
    }
    return ret;
}

int rabin_karp(const string& needle, const string& haystack)
{
    //I'm using long longs to avoid overflow
    long long hash1 = hash(needle);
    long long hash2 = 0;

    //you could use exponentiation by squaring for extra speed
    long long power = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < needle.size(); i++)
        power = (power * PRIME_BASE) % PRIME_MOD;

    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.size(); i++)
    {
        //add the last letter
        hash2 = hash2*PRIME_BASE + haystack[i];
        hash2 %= PRIME_MOD;

        //remove the first character, if needed
        if (i >= needle.size())
        {
            hash2 -= power * haystack[i-needle.size()] % PRIME_MOD;
            if (hash2 < 0) //negative can be made positive with mod
                hash2 += PRIME_MOD;
        }

        //match?
        if (i >= needle.size()-1 && hash1 == hash2)
            return i - (needle.size()-1);
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << rabin_karp("waldo", "willy werther warhol wendy --> waldo <--") << endl;
}
```

Comment: @community Why MOD should be prime number. Can you please give me some source where I could check this. Because here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835946/how-to-reduce-a-bigger-string-in-smaller-string-in-c-probably-by-hashing/5836274#5836274 we have a big discussion about this topic and couldn't come over one opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Some pointers for a fast implementation:

1. Avoid modulo n operation (% in C like languages) use mask n - 1, where n is 2^k,  include the operations for the hash table lookup. Yes, it's possible to produce good hash with a non-prime moduli.
2. Pick multipliers and exponents with good figures of merit, see [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00996-5/S0025-5718-99-00996-5.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while back. Its written in c# but that is very close to c, you will only have to add a couple of parameters. This **should** work but I haven't test this version,  I removed a couple lines that would ignore case or non-word chars. I hope this helps

```
private const int primeBase = 101;
//primeBase^2*[0]+primeBase^1*[1]+primeBase^0*[2]
//==
//primeBase*(primeBase*[0]+[1])+[2]
public static int primeRollingHash(String input, int start, int end)
{
    int acc = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        acc *= primeBase;
        acc += c;
    }
    return acc;
}

public static int primeRollingHash(String input)
{
    return primeRollingHash(input, 0, input.Length - 1);
}

public static int rollHashRight(int currentHashValue, String input, 
                                int start, int newEnd)
{
    if (newEnd == input.Length)
        return currentHashValue;
    int length = newEnd - start - 1;
    int multiplier = primeBase;
    char newChar = input[newEnd];
    int firstValue = input[start];
    if(length>0)
        firstValue *= length * primeBase;
    return (currentHashValue - firstValue) * multiplier + newChar;
}
```