# How to reduce a bigger string in smaller string in C++? Probably by hashing?

Tags: c++, string, compression

I want to compress a bigger string into a smaller string in C++. What are the different ways to do this in C++? The requirement is that output should also be a string.

Comment: If you don't need to uncompress it, then what's the point?  You may as well write a "compression" function that always returns an empty string.

Comment: What do you mean you don't need to uncompress it?! What's the point?!!

Comment: If you are looking for optimizing your memory management, then it's not called compressing. And without decompressing the compressed string the string cannot be used.

Comment: Sounds like homework? If not, I'm curious to know why you want to compress without uncompressing.

Comment: I need a way to get a unique compressed string for every unique bigger string that i want to compress. Probably I should not use word compress. I need to create a unique string of length 30 from string of length 50. Can i hash it?

Comment: @Sam: You are indeed talking about hashing (so you should edit your question and its title).  But note that hashing cannot guarantee uniqueness (unless the output is longer than the input!).

Comment: Yes just hash it and then do a base64 encode on the binary hash. The collision probability for a good hash is extremely low. Lower that the hardware error rate for sure.

Comment: @Oli You can guarantee uniqueness, but only if you know which subset of all length 50 strings you will be getting, and if that subset has less unique strings than the set of all length 30 strings.

Comment: @Null: Yes, true.  I was assuming arbitrary input.

Comment: @CodeInChaos:  Right, and remember that you can truncate a good cryptographic hash to the length you need.

Comment: Which would be the best hashing algorithm to be used then?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't need to uncompress it later:

```
string s = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
s = "";
```

**Edit:** Sounds like you want a hash function - there are a zillion out there, depending on your requirements. Google is your friend.

Comment: Satisfies the question - "I don't need to un-compress it later."

Comment: Reminds me of the algorithm for compressing an image of "Mona Lisa" into a single bit.

Answer (score 0):

As *unaperson* said, Google is your friend: [Data Compression Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression).

Here are a few off the top of my head:
RLE -- Run Length encoded
Huffman
Lepel-Ziv

Answer (score -1):

As I understand from comments of question you don't need to decompress it, but want only for unique strings get unique result. The hashing algorithm which I'm going to explain very easy to understand and works perfect (I've used it lots of times in my practice). It is very simple [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) function which is used in [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) string search algorithms.

Ok let's consider each string as number in 257-base system (because 257 is prime number). Examples:

1. "10" = code('1') * 257 + code('0')
2. "p:;" = code('p') * 257^2 + code('0') * 257 + code(';')

Where `code(char a)` is ascii code of character `a` + 1 (taking +1 to give different result for strings `'\0'`(n times) and `'\0'`(m times)). Of course if the string is big then it's appropriate number can't be stored in `int` or event in `unsigned long long`. But it's not a problem and you can just `MOD` it to `MAX_SIZE` of data-type where you going to store it. So the final code of your hash function is fallowing.

```
unsigned long long hash(const string & s)
{
    unsigned long long ret = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        ret *= 257;
        ret += s[i] + 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added source of this algorithm.

Comment: -1: This is an extremely poor hashing function (its value is determined only by the last 8 characters of the string, assuming `sizeof(long long) == 8`).  One should use an existing hashing algorithm, as they will have been verified to have good properties.

Comment: Isn't "Don't write your own hash  function" as good advice as "don't write your own encryption", or "don't write your own random number generator?"

Comment: @Oli please find two strings that will give same result. I bet you can't! (expect maybe "\0"(n times) and "\0"(m times)) even in this case changing 256 to 257 and takeing `code(a) = ascii_code(a) + 1` my example will work as well.

Comment: @Mihran: Any two strings that have the last 8 characters in common.

Comment: Please try yourself, I think you don't understand the algorithm :)

Comment: @Mihran: I do understand it.  And I just compiled it and tried it out, and it behaves as I said.  If you don't believe me, try feeding it `"Cheeseburger"` and `"WXYZseburger"`.

Comment: +1 You are right. I've mistaken the prime number should be choosen as a base of number system. (actualy I've used version with not 256 but other **prime** number). Now edited to be correct.

Comment: @Mihran: Even after changing the multiplier to 257, this is still very poor.  With a bit of thought, it would not be hard to work out how to find two strings that collide (admittedly, I'm not going to do this now because I'm lazy, but trust me).  @unapersson's advice is correct: don't write your own hash function unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: @If you find I'll delete the answer and never use this again. But as this doesn't happen, let it be, in my opinion, good hashing algorithm, because its distribution function is uniform for all possible values of unsigned long long => you can't find algorithm with better (equal one you can) funciton of distribution.

Comment: If you want to do something tricky and potentially hard to test, and there's readily available free/open source canned software that will do what you want that's written by experts and reviewed by more experts, and you're not an expert, don't write it yourself.  General rule.

Comment: This algorithm isn't my algorithm. It is used by lots of members of programming contests where hashing is needed. (or they use same algorithm, but each time taking `ret` by modulo to some big prime number).

Comment: @Mihran: How do you know that it has a uniform distribution?  Anyway, that means nothing on its own; I can generate a hash with a uniform distribution simply by taking the last 8 characters of the input.  Please accept the fact that this is *not* a good answer.

Comment: I'm repeating again that this is not my algorithm. Take a look to first algorithm in http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/examhash.html in my case instead `prime` I've taken `max_unsigned_long_long` == (in most cases) 2^64 - 1

Comment: @Mihran: This is not the same as your code.  Note the `hash % prime`.

Comment: in my case as prime I've taken max value of unsigned long long. so operation `hash%prime` is going automatically.

Comment: Now I can't find good english source. But look at code in  one http://e-maxx.ru/algo/string_hashes this what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Mihran: You are effectively doing `ret % (1 << 64)`.  This is not prime.

Comment: @Oli because this is not the algorithm of additive hash, but another one, and here it's ok that `MOD` which is `(1 << 64)` in my case wasn't divied to `base` (257). In code from http://e-maxx.ru/algo/string_hashes exacly this algo. Peace:)

Comment: @Mihran: This could go on forever.  It is safe to say that neither of us knows how to write a good hash.  Therefore neither of us should be giving advice on how to write a hash, which is why I have asserted that one should use a good hash function from a reputable source.  Not some random code found on the internet!

Comment: @Oli Ok 1. lets in one second suppose that this algorithm works, then question "Isn't it easy to understand and to write?" I think it is very elegant one. 2. I've used it lots of times. (this two points enough for me to post it as answer for this question). And if you don't agree with me this is your choice to downvote it :)

Comment: @Mihran: Elegance and usefulness are entirely unrelated.  And I don't believe that you can have used it "lots of times", because you suddenly changed your code when I pointed out that it was flawed.  And either way, that's not evidence that it's a good hash.  No offence intended, but designing hash functions is not a task for amateurs.  So, yes, downvote remains!

Comment: You want trustable source ok. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm#Hash_function_used in Rabin-Karps algorithm this hash function is used. and again you can belive or not this is not important for me, but I've used it a lot. P.S. I'm not talking here for getting upvote. The truth is important.

Comment: I even could find the name of this algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash So I'm true)

Comment: @Mihran: From that page: "*all math is done modulo n. The choice of a and n is critical to get good hashing*".

Comment: Take a look to to first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711770/fast-implementation-of-rolling-hash There `a` is 257 and `n` is first prime number after 1000000000, but also there says that `you can choose to just let it overflow unsigned int, but I think it's much more prone to collision (but also faster!)` and this post becomes `communication wiki`. And adding to this that I've tried it many times I'm agin not changing my opinion.

Comment: @Mihran: Right, exactly.  The mathematics of linear congruential generators is complicated; you can't just guess and hope for the best.  (Incidentally, I don't get notified of your replies unless you prefix your comments with @Oli.)