# Searching for a particular String in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, algorithm

I would like to know what is the fastest way / algorithm of checking for the existence of a word in a `String` array. For an example, if I have a String array with 10,000 elements, I would like to know whether it has the word "Human". I can sort the array, no problem.

However, binary search (`Arrays.binarySearch()`) is not allowed. Other collection types like `HashSet`, `HashMap` and `ArrayList` are not allowed too.

Is there any proven algorithm for this? Or any other method? The way of searching should be really really fast.

Comment: Is it binary search that is not allowed, or just using the library implementation of it? Similarly, are you allowed to roll your own hashed data structure?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Hi, You mean HashMap?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: My words are already hashed. Which means, I have them in a 3 character format. For an example, the word "astronaut" will be "!2#"

Comment: No, I meant implementing a hashed data structure yourself, without depending on an existing library implementation.

Answer (score 2):

the fastest way you can sort will result in O(nLogn) complexity
so if you are looking for particular word in unordered data just scan the array with single for cycle, that will cost you O(n)

Comment: `that will cost you O(n*length of word)` for EACH WORD ... very costly .

Comment: length_of_word is not a variable by its nature, so from asymptotic notation 
O(n)=O(100000000000*n)

Comment: @VilenMelkumyan Of course it is a variable. I can easily imagine dictionaries with unbounded word sizes

Comment: yes, but I guess it depends on your data and how you view it, in general if you have an array of strings for sure there is a string that has maximal length and so length of word is bounded. 
you are right if the array of strings varies.

Answer (score 1):

For fastest performance you have to use hashing .
   You can use [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) .
It ensures lesser number of collisions .

```
hash = [0]*base^(n-1) + [1]*base^(n-2) + ... + [n-1]
```

where `base` is a prime number , say `31` .

You need to take modulo also , so integer range is not exceeded , by a `prime number` .

Time complexity : `O(number of characters)` considering multiplication and modulo `O(1)` operation .

A very good explaination is given here : [Fast implementation of Rolling hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711770/fast-implementation-of-rolling-hash)

Answer (score 1):

Build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of the array. It can be built in linear time (assuming a constant size alphabet). Then you can query in linear time as well (time proportional to the query word length). Both preprocessing and query time are asymptotically optimal.

Comment: +1 for bringing this up. Will it be one time cost on creation of the trie? Like if i want to add a group of words to the already created trie, will it again search for that particular node and add to it or create a new trie altogether?

Comment: @bgth Yes, you can insert and delete into and from the trie directly via that algorithm. The runtime there is also linear (optimal), so if you initially start with an empty trie and add the words one after another, you still get linear time overall

Comment: But is it the right tool for finding a whole string as in this question instead of closest fit? Also will it not throw matches for all the nodes which are above? Like, if you are searching for "Hum", will it not throw match for "Hum" and "Huma" and "Human" and "Humanitarian"?

Comment: @bgth: You walk up to the node that represents the string "Human". Then you check whether it has a boolean marker that says "one of the input words is represented by this node". I don't see the problem to be honest. It's definitely the right tool in an algorithmic sense because it has optimal runtime bounds. And it's also very fast in practice (but probably not as fast as a hashing-based approach due to cache misses).

Comment: can you please point me to a book which has details of this and other algorithms for reading?

Comment: @bgth I don't usually learn from books so I can only tell you what other people say. Knuth's books are supposed to be good and Cormen (Introduction to Algorithms) is a classic. I don't like Cormen too much though